# Getting fake user input to a scanner? (rerouting user input from swing fake console to a scanner in a parser)

Tags: java, stream, java.util.scanner

I'm a bit of a novice at java so I'm hoping this will be an easy question to answer.

I'm modding a console/text-based game to also have some GUI, the game normally scans for user input with a scanner in it's parser. I've added a JConsole from Beanshell 2 and redirected output there using tukushans method https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324525/1236210

Now however I need to learn how to get the command < enter>'ed by the user from this console to the scanner in the parser. The code in the parser related to this is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public Parser() 
{
    reader = new Scanner(System.in);
}

...


String inputLine;   // will hold the full input line
    String word1 = null;
    String word2 = null;

    System.out.print("> ");     // print prompt       

    inputLine = reader.nextLine();

    // Find up to two words on the line.
    Scanner tokenizer = new Scanner(inputLine);
    if(tokenizer.hasNext()) {
        word1 = tokenizer.next();      // get first word
        if(tokenizer.hasNext()) {
            word2 = tokenizer.next();      // get second word
            // note: we just ignore the rest of the input line.
        }
    }
    return etc.
```

**My main question would be how does one generally create a fake inputstream and feed it to a scanner like reader here?**

If you can answer that and/or redirect me to good documentation for this, I'd be more than happy ^_^ I'm hoping that with that knowledge I'll figure out a way myself to connect this console to my scanner. If you do however also answer how to do this for the JConsole, that would be simply awesome, and if you do then you should also post it in [Java - How to read user input from BeanShell's JConsole?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155782/java-how-to-read-user-input-from-beanshells-jconsole)

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html)?

Comment: @irrelephant nope when I do `public static String systemFakeIn = "go north"; StringReader theStringReader = new StringReader(systemFakeIn);
        reader = new Scanner(theStringReader);` I get `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)` at `inputLine = reader.nextLine();`